# Error: Command 'test' not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im developing in c9.io in a rails server. I execute 
`rails test` and it works corectly. Next day I execute the same command but instead appear Error: Command 'test' not recognized I do not change anything. How can I restore this command?

Note:`rake test` works perfectly but ruby page http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html and ruby on rails tutorial by Michael Hartl https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages talk about rails test command and it work for me 2 days.

this is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'  
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'  
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'  
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'  
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'  
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'  
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'  
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do    
gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'    
gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'    
gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'    
gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end


group :test do    
gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'    
gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'    
gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'   
end


group :production do      
gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'      
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'  
end
```

Comment: You sure you didn't mean `rake test`? Why don't you try that...

Comment: And what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.2.2 eh? Prior to Rails 5, you had to run tests using the rake tool. With Rails 5, you run tests with `rails test`. Either you a) downgraded your Rails version, or b) you were testing against an entirely different project using Rails 5, or c) you were simply mistaken and were using `rake test` the entire time.

Comment: I think case a is happened. A lot of thanks it help me to solve problem.

Comment: probably should tag this question with the appropriate rails tag version.

Comment: oh, and @MarsAtomic create an answer so I can upvote it and hopefully the original questioner can accept it

Comment: @jaydel Thanks, but this question is probably not going to be of consequential help to future readers. There's actually a category for questions that should be closed due to brainfarts. This kind of thing happens to all of us sooner or later.

Comment: @MarsAtomic it was helpful. I didn't know its specific to Rails 5 and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by MarsAtomic:

Prior to Rails 5, you had to run tests using the rake tool. With Rails 5, you run tests with rails test. Either you a) downgraded your Rails version, or b) you were testing against an entirely different project using Rails 5, or c) you were simply mistaken and were using rake test the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you have not changed anything:

**Step 1**

Make sure you are in your project's directory:

```
cd /path/to/app
```

**Step 2**

Make sure you are using the version of Rails you think you are using:

```
rails -v
```

**Step 3**

Compare that against your application's environment:

If your app is **Rails 4**, this will return information about your app:

```
rake about
```

If your app is **Rails 5**, that will not work, but this will:

```
rails about
```

**Step 4**

Use the appropriate command for the Rails version of your app.

If your app is **Rails 4**:

```
rake test
```

If your app is **Rails 5**:

```
rails test
```